# Is there another way to browse results than each in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, list

First, what is a @books or a @planes (from a select(:all)) in rails? Is it an array? A list? How is it named? The official rails guide about layout and rendering never names it.

Secondly, is there another way to browse it than each do? I have a specific case where i need to browse "by hand" the results, how can i do that?

EDIT :

I want to do that :

```
    <table>
    <% 3.times do %>
    <tr>
      <% 4.times do %>
        <td>
          <%if collection= @collections.next%>
              <%=  collection.main_image.url(:vignette) %>
          <%end%>
        </td>
      <%end%>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
  </table>
```

It is supposed to display an array of 12 (different) collection's pictures. The array is completed even if there is not 12 entry in the result.

The `if collection= @collections.next` is to at the same time test for a next entry and assignating it. Of course it does not works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something on the following lines:

```
<%- array = (1..12).to_a %>

<table>
  <%- array.zip(@collections).each_slice(4) do |collections| %>
    <tr>
    <%- collections.each do |number, collection| %>
      <td><%= collection.main_image.url(:vignette) unless collection.blank? %></td>
    <%- end %>
    </tr>
  <%- end %>
</table>
```

Comment: It works great! but i do not really understand this code. Is this more ruby than rails syntax?

Comment: look at syntax of `Array#zip`, that would probably explain it better. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260

Answer (score 1):

Use `each_slice`. This way you can group your items per row (if that is what you are attempting):

```
collections = (1..20).to_a

collections.each_slice(4) { |collection|
  puts "----------------"
  puts collection.join(" | ")
}
```

Output:

```
----------------
1 | 2 | 3 | 4
----------------
5 | 6 | 7 | 8
----------------
9 | 10 | 11 | 12
----------------
13 | 14 | 15 | 16
----------------
17 | 18 | 19 | 20
```

Comment: if i do a .each, i can display collection.name. and an array wit as many column than i have collection.
As soon as i replace it by each_slice(4) rails says :
undefined method `name' for #<Array:0xa8ce2e0>
Are you sure each_slice work for results?

Comment: @Sylario - you should use `irb` to play with stuff like this. You will progress much faster. `each_slice` groups an array into a bunch of array of slice size. So inside the `each_slice` loop you will get an array of objects that are the size of the slice you selected. Then you loop through THEM. Play with it a bit in `irb`. Use `puts` and `inspect`, and you will soon figure it out. For example in `irb` try this: `puts (1..20).each_slice(4) { |a| puts a.inspect }`. Now you see what it does. `irb` is your best friend.